# FB like not working as expected

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

Creating a page with multiple "like" buttons on it. I'm using their XFBML syntax so when someone "likes" one of the items on the page they can post a message on their wall (default behaviour w/ XFMBL). Sometimes the pop-up shows up but sometimes it flashes away - can't seem to find a pattern why. I have tried this in Opera, IE, FF (latest released versions of each).

Eveything looks according to FB's documentation. See the page at: http://ncaa.rmingorance.mouse.engauge.com/bracket

(note, I can't use the iframe version because I can't give it enough width for the pop-up to work - the pop-up should always work with XFBML according to the docs)

Comment: I am having the same exact issue here: http://www.facebook.com/LOrealParisHungary?sk=app_197149540333340 Did you come up with any solution?

Comment: Yes - I found a solution for it - in my case the problem was that the pages that were being liked didn't actually exist yet. When we created the pages to be liked everything magically started working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reach the URL above but it returns a 500 error.  Once you have it up again, please try using the Facebook linter to make sure everything is correct:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint